# How do you construct a fluid api without calling each method in the chain

Tags: javascript

In fluid APIs like the one provided in [Chalk's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) they give you the ability to chain methods together.

`chalk.red.bgYellow('string')`

These methods can also be used on their own:

`chalk.red('string')`

How can we string these together without parentheses. I realise that each method will return the object with all these properties & methods on it. I just don't understand how they can be a method *as well* as an object with methods on it.

I have looked at the source code of Chalk but it's slightly out of my reach currently.

Comment: Any function is an object in JavaScript, and can have any properties that you assign on it. Notice that in `chalk.red.bgYellow`, `red` is not actually called.

Comment: So is red itself a constructor function?

Comment: No, it's just a method. Maybe the property is a getter that dynamically creates the function, or maybe it just was statically assigned, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably along the lines of how it's achieved.
Essentially, you have getters on an internal member object. These change the state of that object, while also returning the constructor function itself.

We then add methods to the prototype object of the constructor (or via es6 class syntax sugar) which set the state of the internal object, while also calling a method on that object (`log()` for example). These methods also set the state of the internal object.

This could definitely be cleaner but I think this is how this type of functionality is achieved in practice.

If anyone has any thoughts let me know.

> One thing to note: Initially I was returning the `chk` object from within the constructor. Of course, this doesn't work because then we don't have a prototype object on our constructor function, meaning I cannot add methods to it. It's a case of continuously returning the constructor function, and accessing the internal object's state from the methods on the prototype.

```js
const Chalk = function () {
 const _this = this
 this.chk = {
  get red () {
   this.color = 'red'
   return _this
  },
  get blue () {
   this.color = 'blue'
   return _this
  },
  get bgYellow () {
   this.bg = 'yellow'
   return _this
  },
  get bgBlue () {
   this.bg = 'blue'
   return _this
  },
  log(msg) {
   this.msg = msg
   console.log(`color: ${this.color} \nbg: ${this.bg} \nmsg: ${this.msg}
   `)
  }
 }
}

Chalk.prototype.red = function (msg) {
 this.chk.color = 'red'
 this.chk.log(msg)
}

Chalk.prototype.blue = function (msg) {
 this.chk.color = 'blue'
 this.chk.log(msg)
}

const chalk = new Chalk().chk

chalk.bgYellow.blue('test')
```